# Heroku not displaying dynamic variable link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a services model and each object has a website attribute. It works locally, but on heroku, the teks link doesn't show up.

```
<%= link_to service.website, service.website %>
```

I have assets compile working, the rails12factor gem, I can't figure out why. I think it has something to do with heroku security with bare links.

Please help. I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Check your logs - `heroku logs`

Comment: No errors in the log. Just...nothing. Works locally.